# How to handle php generated images (without extension)?

Tags: php, curl

Is it possible to work with following kind of image urls?

```
http://product-images.barneys.com/is/image/Barneys/503230930_product_1
```

Currently I'm using following code to determine remote image formats. But I don't know how to handle the above mentioned example. Thats one example. Normally they do it for dynamic image resizing.

```
if($source['extension'] == 'png') {
$type = 'image/png';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$f = tempnam("./", "TMP0");
file_put_contents($f,file_get_contents("http://product-images.barneys.com/is/image/Barneys/503230930_product_1"));
if(getimagesize($f)){
$type = 'image/png';
}
```

`$f` file has now the image do whatever you want or delete it using `unlink($f);`

Comment: Thanks, this one is simple. :)

Comment: Please Note My code contained an error I missed checking if the file is image or not which I have fixed Now.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of [`finfo::file`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) extension. You don't need to use `cURL` for this context.

```
<?php
$remoteImgTempName = 'someimg';
file_put_contents($remoteImgTempName,file_get_contents('http://product-images.barneys.com/is/image/Barneys/503230930_product_1'));
echo finfo_file(finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE), $remoteImgTempName);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
image/jpeg
```